# Pass an array to a function without explicitly declaring the array beforehand

Tags: c, arrays

I have this function that I call a bunch of times:

```
void shifter(int [])
{
//...
}
```

I want to call it with an array that I allocate on the fly, something like:

```
shifter({1,2,3,0});
```

I know the above example doesn't work. Is there a syntax that does work so I don't have to explicitly declare the array each time I call the function?

This is C, not C++.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Compound Literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) (Available in C99+):

```
shifter( (int []){1,2,3,0} );
```

Note: Both GCC and clang support it as an extension in C90 mode as well.

Comment: The parens fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a function in C, you're passing the adress of the first element, not the content of the array itself. So i don't think there's a way to do that.

If there's really only 4 parameters, you can use 4 int it won't be too long to do. If there's more than that, why not using an aray then ?

Comment: Because the array can be variable length. Passing 4 int is rigid.

Comment: Ok. Consider the other answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If you could consider using C++, use the following:

```
shifter(new int[](1,2,3,0));
```

Comment: It's not C++. I wrote that.